# regex and rename the variables in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to regex the variables from a file; the files look like:

```
   ...unknown lines...
    @    legend hgap 1
    @     s0  legend  "foo"
    @     s2  legend  "bar"
    ...unknown lines
```

a simple regex is

```
^@[ \t]*s\d*[ \t]*(legend)[ \t]*[A-z0-9"_]*
```

that matches my need.

But now, I need to rename `S0` (yes,capital `S`) to `foo` and S1 to `bar`.
How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
^(@\s*)S\d*(\s*legend\s*\")([A-z0-9_]*)(\")
```

and replace with:

```
$1$3$2$3$4
```

see demo here: https://regex101.com/r/1GkEYQ/2

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to change s0 to foo , here's a hint :

```
>>> s = re.sub('s0','foo','    @     s0  legend  "foo"')
>>> print(s)
    @     foo  legend  "foo"
```